# Как сделать загрузку картинки с сайта в базу данных Parse

Tags: javascript, parse.com

Как сделать загрузку картинки в parse.com

Answer (score 1):

Диалоговое окно для выбора картинки:

```
<input type="file" id="profilePhotoFileUpload">
```

Отправка на сервер:

```
var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
    var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
    var name = "photo.jpg";
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
}
```